# Why is Div negative margin-bottom not working

Tags: html

I have two child divs in a parent div.
And child 1 is `margin-top: -50px`,
child 2 is `margin-bottom: -50px`.

But it seems that negative `margin-bottom` doesn't work, while `margin-top` works fine.

Can someone tell me why?

You can see the code here in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aotian16/Lxhod5ne/#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATED ANSWER

Yours is a case of [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/css_box_model/mastering_margin_collapsing), and in this case, the top and bottom margins of the parent element collapses with the top margin of the first child and bottom margin of the last child.

Margin collapsing can occur when:

> **No content separating parent and descendants.**
> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of one or more of its descendant blocks; or no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of one or more of its descendant blocks, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

To demonstrate, you could add a padding to the outer div to give space around `#parent`. Then you would notice that `#parent` stretched upwards and downwards to cover the same area as its children `#child1` and `#child2`. So the negative margins got applied also to the parent.

```css
#container {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

#parent {
  background-color: beige;
}

#child1,
#child2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#child2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Options To Fix It

There are a few options you could do for your situation:

1. Add top and bottom borders to `#parent`. If you do not want the border to show, you can colour the border transparent

```css
#container {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

#parent {
  background-color: beige;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

#child1,
#child2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#child2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child0"></div>
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Add top and bottom paddings to `#parent`.

```css
#container {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

#parent {
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 1px 0;
}

#child1,
#child2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#child2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child0"></div>
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Change `#parent` to a flexbox. You may have to adjust styles of other child/descendant elements you have not shown in your example.

```css
#container {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

#parent {
  background-color: beige;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#child1,
#child2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#child2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child0"></div>
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**REFERENCES**

- [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/css_box_model/mastering_margin_collapsing)
- [The Rules of Margin Collapse](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse)

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

> I decided to update my answer (see update above) when I realised the result (of running the code snippet) on my original answer is not quite the same as the result shown in the question. And me adding a border in `#parent` in my original answer, stopped the margin collapse.

I think it does. The negative bottom margin of the child element will make that child's bottom edge be lower than its parent's bottom edge. If you add a grey border to the parent, you will notice the second child element is sitting lower than the parent.

```css
#parent {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* ADDED FOR VISIBILITY */
}
#child1,
#child2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#child1 {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
#child2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  border: 1px solid #000; /* ADDED FOR VISIBILITY */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

@aotian16, you are actually correct that margin-bottom is not behaving as you expect.

Frank Fajardo's answer accidentally gives the illusion that it is working (working meaning moving the aliceblue box down -50px). This is not actually what is happening.

To explain negative margins: Negative top and left margins will move the item they are applied on to the top or left. Negative BOTTOM and RIGHT margins however, do NOT move the item they are applied on to the bottom or right. A negative right margin actually pulls content to the right of your element closer to it, and a negative bottom margin pulls content underneath your item upwards.

The reason the accepted answer appears to show the aliceblue item moving down, is:

1st: There is a negative margin applied to the TOP of child 1, this allows child 2 to move up with it, while the background item stays in place.

2nd: Applying the negative margin to child 2 after the negative top margin is applied to child 1 does NOT move child 2 down past the background. It actually pulls the background color UP into child 2. Turn on and off the negative bottom margin and watch that child 2 does not move down, the background moves up.

So it's not that the negative bottom margin is not working, it is just not working as we assumed it would. I wish it did work in this way..

```
#parent {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* ADDED FOR VISIBILITY */
}
#child1,
#child2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#child1 {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
#child2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  border: 1px solid #000; /* ADDED FOR VISIBILITY */
}
<div>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">

    </div>
    <div id="child2">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @David_Mays, firstly, my original answer *did not give an illusion that it is working*. It actually fixed the problem with a collapsing margin.